# Moving array of smaller structs into array of larger structs in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, casting, padding

Today I was working on a problem of moving an array of smaller structs directly into an array of larger structs (`arrayNew`) (essentially upgrading the smaller structs to store more information). The smaller structs needed to be read from a HDD in one *single* read operation into the array of new 'upgraded' larger structs, a function would be called to do the 'upgrading'. Also all the new fields in the structs that were read from the hard drive would be set to `'0'`.
Other more simple solutions that I tried were:

- Creating a local array of the old structures (`arrayOld`), loading the structures from the HDD into it then simply looping through the empty array of the new structures (`arrayNew`) and manually moving each structs contents from `arrayOld` into `arrayNew`. (e.g. `arrayNew[i].x = arrayOld[i].x;` )
  The problem with this is that in my case the arrays I was working with were very large and too large for the stack ( about 1mb for each array) causing a segmentation fault the instant the upgrading function was called.
- Another viable solution was to create a dynamic array of the old structures (`arrayDy`) and load the old structures into `arrayDy` and then again manually moving each structs contents from `arrayDy` into `arrayNew`. (e.g. `arrayNew[i].y = arrayDy[i].y;` ) This addressed the issue of running out of stack memory.

After implementing the second solution. I decided to experiment and develop a solution that uses no dynamically allocated memory and loads the array of old structures from the HHD directly into the larger array of larger structs `arrayNew` in one read operation and manipulate the contents of `arrayNew` in memory to pad out the missing values that are there due to the array being bigger.

I will post my solution below in a scaled down version of what I implemented, using the following structs for my example:

```
typedef struct INNER_STRUCT_ {

    int i_item1;
    int i_item2;
    char i_item3;

} INNER_STRUCT;

typedef struct SMALL_STRUCT_ {

    int item1;
    char item2;
    INNER_STRUCT item3;

} SMALL_STRUCT;

typedef struct BIG_STRUCT_ {

    int item1;
    char item2;
    INNER_STRUCT item3;
    INNER_STRUCT item4;

} BIG_STRUCT;
```

Comment: You are loading those 100 structs from disk with 1 call or with 100 calls?

Comment: If you are short of stack space check the alignment of your variables and allocate  the most restrictive first. You space calcs assume you are packing the structures

Comment: If you are limited in stack space, why don't you store the array somewhere else(using dynamic memory allocation, for example)?

Comment: Purely in C, you will have to perform each copy operation separately (i.e., iterate it 100 times). Depending on your processor, some (like DSPs) have designated operations specifically for this purpose. But that is not a part of the C-language standard of course.

Comment: the function that loads the struct from the disk is called once, and will give an error if the load is not successful. I am currently working on a solution using dynamic memory , but was considering if the other option is possible. @TimChild would I need to read up somewhere on the alignment of variables? Thanks

Comment: This is a matter of serialization to/deserialization from disk, so with out providing the routines that perform those  two operations it will be hard to answer. A typical solution would be to adjust the deserialization routine or to create a new routine to create a structB_ array instead of structA_ array.

Comment: my apologies , I did not write the question as clearly as I could have done but I have found a solution and posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I propose and used as a solution basically loads the smaller structs for the HDD ( a file in this case) into the array of new larger structs and then rearranges the block of memory so that each field can be accessed properly. The code to illustrate this is below, and is an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct INNER_STRUCT_ {

    int i_item1;
    int i_item2;
    char i_item3;

} INNER_STRUCT;

typedef struct SMALL_STRUCT_ {

    int item1;
    char item2;
    INNER_STRUCT item3;

} SMALL_STRUCT;

typedef struct BIG_STRUCT_ {

    int item1;
    char item2;
    INNER_STRUCT item3;
    INNER_STRUCT item4;
    /* 
    Note that the big struct is exactly the same as the small 
    struct with one extra field - Key to this method working 
    is the fact that the extension to the struct is appended
    at the end, in an array of the structs will be placed one 
    after the other in memory with no gaps*/

} BIG_STRUCT;

void printSmallStruct (SMALL_STRUCT *inStruct, int count) {
    // Print everything inside given small struct
    printf("\n\n Small struct %d, item1: %d \n",count,inStruct->item1);
    printf(" Small struct %d, item2: %c \n",count,inStruct->item2);
    printf(" Small struct %d, item3.i_item1: %d \n",count,inStruct->item3.i_item1);
    printf(" Small struct %d, item3.i_item2: %d \n",count,inStruct->item3.i_item2);
    printf(" Small struct %d, item3.i_item3: %c \n",count,inStruct->item3.i_item3);
}

void printBigStruct (BIG_STRUCT *inStruct, int count) {
    // Print everything inside given big struct
    printf("\n\n Big struct %d, item1: %d \n",count,inStruct->item1);
    printf(" Big struct %d, item2: %c \n",count,inStruct->item2);
    printf(" Big struct %d, item3.i_item1: %d \n",count,inStruct->item3.i_item1);
    printf(" Big struct %d, item3.i_item2: %d \n",count,inStruct->item3.i_item2);
    printf(" Big struct %d, item3.i_item3: %c \n",count,inStruct->item3.i_item3);
    printf(" Big struct %d, item4.i_item1: %d \n",count,inStruct->item4.i_item1);
    printf(" Big struct %d, item4.i_item1: %d \n",count,inStruct->item4.i_item2);
    printf(" Big struct %d, item4.i_item1: %c \n",count,inStruct->item4.i_item3);
}

int main() {


    SMALL_STRUCT smallStructArray[5];       // The array of small structs that we will write to a file then read

    BIG_STRUCT   loadedBigStructArray[5];   // The large array of structs that we will read the data from the file into

    int i;  // Counter that we will use

    FILE *pfile;    // pointer to our file stream

    void *secondary_ptr;    // void pointer that we will use to 'chop' memory into the size we want

    /* Fill the array of structs (smallStructArray) */
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    /* We fill each field with different data do we can ID that the right data is in the right fields */
        smallStructArray[i].item1 = 111;
        smallStructArray[i].item2 = 'S';
        INNER_STRUCT*    temp = &smallStructArray[i].item3;
        temp->i_item1 = 777;
        temp->i_item2 = 999;
        temp->i_item3 = 'I';
    }


    /* Write the contents of smallStructArray to binary file then display it */
    pfile = fopen("test.dat","wb");
    if (pfile!=NULL){
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fwrite(&smallStructArray[i],sizeof(SMALL_STRUCT),1,pfile);
    }
    fclose(pfile);
    }
    else{
    printf("Unable to open file!");
    return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         printSmallStruct(&smallStructArray[i],i);
    }

    /* Clear array of big structs using memset  */
    memset(&loadedBigStructArray[0],0,sizeof(loadedBigStructArray));

    /* Here we read from the smallStructArray that was aved to file into the  loadedBigStructArray */
    pfile = fopen("test.dat","rb");
    if (pfile !=NULL){
    /*
    He we pass fread the following:     size_t fread(void *args1, size_t args2, size_t args3, FILE *args4)
    args1   - a pointer to the beginning of a block of memory, in our case the beginning of the 
          array loadedBigStructArray.

    args2   - the size of the ammout of bytes we wish to read, in our case the size of a SMALL_STRUCT, 
          the size one of the elments in the array saved to the file.

    args3   - the ammount of elements to read, in our case five (which is the number of elements the 
          array saved to the file has. 

    args4   - a pointer to a FILE that specifies our input stream.

    Essentially what fread will do here is read a block of bytes the size of the array we saved to 
    the file (smallStructArray) into the array in memory loadedBigStructArray from the 
    beggining of loadedBigStructArray. Fig 1 illustrates what this will look like in memory.
    */
    fread(&loadedBigStructArray,sizeof(SMALL_STRUCT),5,pfile);
    fclose(pfile);
    }
    else{
    printf("Unable to open file!");
    return 1;
    }
    /* 
    Due to the way the array on the file has been read into the array in memory, if we try 
    to access the data in loadedBigStructArray only the first 5 values will be valid, due to 
    the  memory not being in the order we want. We need to re-arrange the data in loadedBigStructArray
    */

    /* 
    Here we use a void pointer to point to  the beggining of the loadedBigStructArray.
    we will use this pointer to 'chop' the data loadedBigStructArray into SMALL_STRUCT 
    sized 'chunks' we can read from.

    Due to the way pointers and arrays work in C we can cast the void pointer to any type we want
    and get a chunk of memory that size begginnig from the pointer and its off set.
    E.g. : int temp = ((int *)void_ptr)[i];  
    This example above will give us an integer 'temp' that was taken from memory beggining from position
    void_ptr in memory and its offset i. ((int *)void_ptr) casts the pointer to type int and [i] dereferances
    the pointer to location i.
    */
    secondary_ptr = &loadedBigStructArray;

    /* 
    Not we are going through the array backwards so that we can rearange the data with out overwriting 
    data in a location that has data which we havent moved yet. As the bottom end of the loadedBigStructArray
    is essentially empty we can shift data down that way.
    */
    for (i = 5; i > -1; i=i-1) {


    SMALL_STRUCT temp = ((SMALL_STRUCT *)secondary_ptr)[i]; // dereference pointer to SMALL_STRUCT [i] inside loadedBigStructArray call it 'temp'

    /*
    Now that we have dereferenced a pointer a given SMALL_STRUCT inside loadedBigStructArray called 'temp'
    we can use temp to move the data inside temp to its corresponding position in loadedBigStructArray 
    which rearragnes the data.
    */
    loadedBigStructArray[i].item1 = temp.item1;
    loadedBigStructArray[i].item2 = temp.item2;
    loadedBigStructArray[i].item3.i_item1 = temp.item3.i_item1;
    loadedBigStructArray[i].item3.i_item2 = temp.item3.i_item2;
    loadedBigStructArray[i].item3.i_item3 = temp.item3.i_item3;

    /* We then fill the new field to be blank */
    loadedBigStructArray[i].item4.i_item1 = 0;
    loadedBigStructArray[i].item4.i_item2 = 0;
    loadedBigStructArray[i].item4.i_item3 = '0';
    }

    /* Print our new structures */
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         printBigStruct(&loadedBigStructArray[i],i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Visualization of technique:

[image: Visualization of technique]

When fread does the single read operation of the array saved on disk into the array in memory due to it being smaller it will take up the first potion of the array in memory but the 'bottom' section could be anything, if we try to access the data in the new array with the current handles we have on the data we will either get inaccurate information or a bad piece of memory. We have to rearrange this data before we can use any of our handles on the structs in the array.

Comment: please comment if anything does not make sense

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible - you can use `union` for that. C99 standard makes a special guarantee that can be used to implement your requirement:

> 6.5.2.3-5: One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the complete type of the union is visible.

Your `structA_` and `structB_` do share a common initial sequence, so creating a `union` and accessing the structs through it would do the trick:

```
union {
    structA a;
    structB b;
} u;
memset(&u.b, 0, sizeof(structB)); // Zero out the bigger structB
loadFromHdd(&u.a); // Load structA part into the union
// At this point, u.b is valid, with its structA portion filled in
// and structB part zeroed out.
```

Note that you cannot do it to an array (unless, of course, you make an array of `union`s). Each `structA` needs to be loaded individually into the `union`, from which it could then be read as `structB`.

Comment: How is that possible if the data on the HHD is "condensed" as an array of smaller structures, and the data in the RAM needs to be "expanded" so that each smaller structure is followed by 20 bytes of additional data?

Comment: @barakmanos I added a note to mention that this is not possible to do with an array. I assume that OP can read `struct`s one by one.

Comment: OK, but I'm pretty sure OP knows how to do that already, with or without the `union` (which will yield the same runtime performance anyway).